# Evaluating $b^*a^*\cap a^*b^*$ to a minimal regular expression

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

> Evaluate to a minimal expression: $b^*a^*\cap a^*b^*$

To me, the only elements to both sets are the empty string, strings containing only $a$, and strings containing only $b$, so isn't  the answer just $a^*\cup b^*$?

This was a midterm problem and the professor marked the answer incorrect.

Comment: What is your definition of *minimal* for regular expressions?

Comment: Not 100% sure to be honest. Prof. never showed an example like it in the class (and there's no HW in the class) nor was there anything like it in the notes. I just assumed that he wanted us to simplify the expression into something smaller.

Comment: I suppose that one could argue that in some sense $a^*\cup bb^*$ is ‘smaller’, since there’s no overlap in $a^*$ and $bb^*$; I can’t think of any other reason not to consider $a^*\cup b^*$ minimal. (The same would go for $aa^*\cup b^*$, of cours.) But in sheer symbol count it’s certainly not smaller.

Comment: My professor responded back. He said that   $b^*$ needs a lambda and $a^*$ needs a lambda, so the answer could not be $a^* \cup b^*$. I don't get it...

Comment: It sounds as if he’s objecting that $a^*\cup b^*$ is redundant, because both $a^*$ and $b^*$ generate the empty word; that’s the one possibility that occurred to me above. Ask him whether $a^*\cup bb^*$ is correct: it generates the same language, and $a^*$ and $bb^*$ have no overlap. (You could equally well use $aa^*\cup b^*$.